# Invalid JDK home selected : Unity 5.3.5f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

The path you specified does not look like a valid JDK installation .
Android development requires at least JDK 7(1.7), having JRE only is not enough.
please make sure you are selecting a suitable JDK home directory, or download 
and install the latest JDK:
http://wwww.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/doenloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Edit -> Preferences -> Externals Tools you can see a place where you should place the path to your JDK instalation.

As you see in the error log, it says that you need at least 1.7. So download it and place the path there.